# Does NuSoap have to be configured a certain way when calling from WCF?

Tags: php, wcf

I'm trying to call a php webservice using WCF. I googled some public php services to see if I could replicate the error I was receiving and I created 2 different unit tests to demonstrate.

The test that failed I get the following error:
System.ServiceModel.ProtocolException: The content type text/xml; charset=ISO-8859-1 of the response message does not match the content type of the binding (text/xml; charset=utf-8). If using a custom encoder, be sure that the IsContentTypeSupported method is implemented properly. The first 601 bytes of the response were: '

Here are the unit tests:

```
[TestMethod]
public void WCF_Call_To_SiteInspect() {
    //This service doesn't work. It gets the same communication error as our own servers
    var soapClien = new SiteInspect.SiteInspectPortClient();

    var response = soapClien.doSiteInspect("Any", "Any", "www.google.com");
    Assert.IsTrue(response.serverTime.Length > 0);
}



[TestMethod]
public void WCF_Call_To_FinnService() {
    //This service works.... in looking at the wsdl it appears that it references a separate wsdl file. Is this the reason?
    var soapClient = new NuSoapFinnService.finnwordsPortTypeClient();

    var finnLyric = soapClient.getRandomNeilFinnLyric("text");
    Assert.IsTrue(finnLyric.Length > 0);
}
```

The test case on the bottom (the Finn service) passed at the following URL: http://www.nickhodge.com/nhodge/finnwords/finnwords.wsdl

The first test case failed given the following URL: http://www.flash-db.com/services/ws/siteInspect.wsdl

The only difference I can see in the wsdl is the Finn service references an extraneous file. xmlns:tns="http://www.nickhodge.com/nhodge/finnwords/finnwords.wsdl . Is this bug with WCF that expects the wsdl in a specific format?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Make sure to set the UTF-8 encoding using *soap_defencoding* in the PHP code.

If you want some more related information, see [this blog post.](http://www.jaylee.org/post/2007/01/Playing-with-WCF-and-NuSOAP-072.aspx)

Comment: Works fine. Just addedd the line: $server->soap_defencoding = 'utf-8';